# How do I grab a QPixmap of a QtDataVizualisation in a QWidget and save to file?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to make a 3D scatter plot using QtDataVisualizationQ3DScatter and then to take a QPixmap of that and save to file.

Here is my code.

```
    //set up the 3D scatter chart
    QtDataVisualization::Q3DScatter *graph = new QtDataVisualization::Q3DScatter();
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
    QtDataVisualization::QScatter3DSeries *series = new QtDataVisualization::QScatter3DSeries;

    //set up the data variable
    QtDataVisualization::QScatterDataArray data;

    //add data to the data variable
    for (int i; i < nodes.size(); i = i + 1)
    {
        data << QVector3D(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
    }

    //add the data to series
    series->dataProxy()->addItems(data);

    //add series to graph
    graph->addSeries(series);

    //set the graph properties
    graph->activeTheme()->setType(QtDataVisualization::Q3DTheme::ThemeArmyBlue);
    graph->scene()->activeCamera()->setCameraPreset(QtDataVisualization::Q3DCamera::CameraPresetIsometricRight);
    graph->seriesList().at(0)->setMesh(QtDataVisualization::QAbstract3DSeries::MeshPoint);
    graph->setShadowQuality(QtDataVisualization::QAbstract3DGraph::ShadowQuality(0));

    //widget->show();
    const QRect rectangle(0,0,widget->width(),widget->height());
    QPixmap test = widget->grab(rectangle);
    test.save(QString(workingDirectory) + "/test.png", "PNG");
```

When I uncomment the "widget->show()", the test.png is just a white square but the widget comes up and shows the full 3DScatter. When I comment out the "widget->show()", test.png is still just a white square. I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: What's `nodes`, `x`, `y`, `z`?

Answer (score 1):

When commenting `widget->show()`, add a `widget->repaint()` call to force the widget to be painted/rendered before saving it in the file.

Comment: This still does not do anything. I still get a white box :/
Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is quite old but for anyone who's interested:

QAbstract3DGraph has a function renderToImage. This is inherited by Q3DScatter.

You should be able to grab a qimage of your scene using:

```
QImage myImage = graph->renderToImage();
```

and then convert this to a pixmap:

```
QPixmap p;
p.convertFromImage(myImage);
```